# Limit IIS CPU but not ignore requests

Tags: c#, iis, cpu

In a project we have an Java application, that make requests to an C# application allocated IIS, all is installed on a same little computer.
The problem is that the usage IIS CPU is very high, when make 3 simultaneous requests the CPU is in aprox 80%, and when make 4 requests the computer is blocked.

We need that go down this CPU usage but without kill any request, if necessary, they can be slowed down.

We aren't expert in IIS.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: since this question is about configuring IIS, and _not at all_ about programming, server fault might be a better place.

Comment: Is possible that the problem is related to the application, that it is a C# service working with EmguCV, the C# wrapper of OpenCV

Comment: possible? yes. but without knowing _anything_ about your implementation it is impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks, Franz
Our implementation is very simple, it takes image from a Basler camera and make some process using EmguCV, basically using a call to [MatchTemplate method](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.0/document/html/ee43f981-70ee-04c2-4c10-764da38f0781.htm). Also is truth that the processor is very tight, a N2800 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the application pool and click advance setting.

Under the CPU section, Configures the maximum percentage of CPU time (in 1/1000ths of one percent) that the worker processes in an application pool are allowed to consume over a period of time as indicated by the resetInterval attribute. (ex: 25% would be 25000) If the limit set by the limit attribute is exceeded, an event is written to the event log and an optional set of events can be triggered. These optional events are determined by the action attribute.

The default value is 0, which disables CPU limiting.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Bruce for your help. Does this limit cause that the request remains pending and are resolved later or will be killed returning some error?

Comment: Requests that cannot be processed immediately enter the request queue and wait for idle threads. Only if the waiting time exceeds the setting of the application pool, a timeout error will be returned to the client.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much, Bruce. I think that is a very relevant information to solve our problem.